# Why we can't publish a NetService using the UDP type on iOS?

Tags: ios, udp, bonjour

I want to publish a NetService on iOS, I create a NetService like this:

```
let netService = NetService(domain: "local.", type: "_demo._tcp.", name: "demo", port: 0)
```

and then I publish it, so far, it works fine.But when I change the type to `_demo._udp.` I got this error info:

`service did not publish,error:["NSNetServicesErrorDomain": 10, "NSNetServicesErrorCode": -72004]`

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Can you edit your question to show more code that reproduces the error and where you see the error?  I was able to create and publish a service using the code you have shown

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi~ Thank your for your reply. Have you change the type to `_demo._udp` ?
below is the problem code:  

`let netService = NetService(domain: "local.", type: "_demo._udp.", name: "demo", port: 0)`

Comment: Using Port 0 doesn't make sense; You need to specify the port of the UDP socket that is listening.  If I change 0 to, say, 9001, then I can publish the service and see it using `dns-sd`